# How can I create my own keys for the AES algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, key, aes

How can I create my own keys for encrypting a string using AES algorithm in Java instead of using

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
```

which creates a random key?

Answer (score 4):

By using a [SecretKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html):

```
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "AES");
```

Answer (score 2):

`kgen` is not a key, actual key is your `SecretKeySpec` object. You can create your key using raw bytes...see the below example...

```
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); 
            kgen.init(128);
            byte raw[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
            SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            //SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
            //byte keybytes[] = key.getEncoded();
            //SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(keybytes, "AES");
```

Comment: Note that you can directly use `SecretKeySpec` as a key (it implements the `SecretKey` interface) if you have an algorithm that takes random bytes as a key. This is at least true for AES and DES ABC keys (for use in DESede), in the latter the parity bits are ignored. If you store a key as a field, I would still use the [SecretKeyFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html) to create a "fail fast" scenario.

Comment: Ohk...thnks for the vital info..:)